# Objects on top of colored objects change color - ILLUSTRATOR

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector, transparency

I am working with vector graphics designing mugs, but whenever I place an object on top of the mug, the object is changing color. I am noticing it is also happening to all my objects. The top object looks like it is under another object that would have its opacity down. I can't figure out why it is doing this to me. The waves are above the mug body, but still keep messing with the colors. The only thing I can think of is that all my colors are from the Pantone + Coated Color Book. I've worked like this for a while, and this is a new issue I am having.

[image: The waves are on top of the body shape. All objects are 100% Opacity.]

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly confident that this **has** to be due to either a *blend mode* or *opacity* setting somewhere. Without direct file examination, it's **impossible** to state *where*.

An easy way to *find* something with an Appearance setting it to merely look at the **Layers Panel**. If the little circle on the right side is filled in then *that* object or layer has an Appearance setting --- which *may be* a blend mode or opacity alteration.

[image]

If a *layer itself* has Appearance setting then every *object* on that layer will also show 
the filled circle (sometimes referred to as a "meatball").